# AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta when login by email

Tags: django, forms, email, authentication

I had correct working form to register and login user using username. I add field email to above forms and change to login by email field. Now registered working but login is not. In view sign_in authentication have None value. I have a error 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'.

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ClassAtSchool(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, 
    blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_at_school = models.ManyToManyField(ClassAtSchool)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_at_school = models.ForeignKey(ClassAtSchool, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

views

```
def sign_up(request):
    context ={}
    who ={"teacher": Teacher, "student": Student}
    form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    context['form'] = form
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid() and request.POST.get("who"):
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            person = who[request.POST.get("who")]
            person(user=user).save()
            messages.success(request, f'{user.email} registered succesfull')
            return render(request, 'registration/sign_up.html', context)

    return render(request, 'registration/sign_up.html', context)

def sign_in(request):
    context = {}
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context['form'] = form
    if form.is_valid():
        print('test1')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        print(f'email: {email}')
        print(f'user: {user}')
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print('test3')
        attempt = request.session.get('attempt') or 0
        request.session['attempt'] = attempt + 1
        return render(request, 'registration/sign_in.html', context)
    return render(request, 'registration/sign_in.html', context)
```

forms

```
class UserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserSignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True

    who = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[('student', 'Student'), ('teacher', 'Teacher')],
        label="",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(
            attrs={'style':'max-width: 20em; ', 'autocomplete':'off', })
)
    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Minimum 8 characters")],
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm password",
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(8, message="Minimum 8 characters"), ],
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('who', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', )
        help_texts = {"username": None}
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={}),

        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserSignUpForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if password != confirm_password:
            msg = _(f'Password and confirm password does not match')
            self.add_error('password', msg)
            self.add_error('confirm_password', msg)


    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_tag = 'false'
    helper.attrs = {"novalidate": True, 'autocomplete':'off'}
    helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    helper.field_class = 'col-md-8 '
    helper.label_class = 'col-md-4'
    helper.layout = Layout(
        Row(
            Column(
                Field('who', css_class='form-group', style='margin-left:200px'),
                Field('username', css_class='form-group ', style=''),
                Field('email', css_class='form-group'),
                Field('first_name', css_class='form-group'),
                Field('last_name', css_class='form-group'),
                Field('password', css_class='form-group'),
                Field('confirm_password', css_class='form-group'),

                FormActions(
                    Submit('save', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-primary"),
                    Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
                ),

        )
    )
)

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control"
    }))
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "id": "user-password"
            }
        )
    )
    def clean_username(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        qs = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email) # thisIsMyUsername == 
thisismyusername
        if not qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This is an invalid user.")
        if qs.count() != 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This is an invalid user.")
        return email


helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_tag = 'false'
helper.attrs = {'autocomplete':'off'}
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.field_class = 'col-md-8 '
helper.label_class = 'col-md-4'
helper.layout = Layout(
    Row(
        Column(
            Field('email', css_class='form-group ', style=''),
            Field('password', css_class='form-group'),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Sign in', css_class="btn-primary"),
                Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
                ),

        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Could you also provide your `User` model? it is django core model or your custom model?

Comment: I use User django core model and email is it field and I also use custom users to add diff fields. I add my custom models in post.

Comment: first of all in django user model, username field used as enter point, and you can not use email as login field

Comment: Did you change your `USERNAME_FIELD` to `email`?

Comment: I stay with username auth

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i find answer. I must do custom Model Manager but I stay with username auth.